# Oregon adoption consent and revocability - legal requirements are not required?

Tags: oregon, parental-rights

According to [ORS 109.321](http://www.oregonlaws.org/ors/109.321) consent to adoption cannot be revoked once 6 conditions are met, one of those being a duly signed and attested Certificate of Irrevocability and Waiver.

I recently spoke with someone from the Child Welfare Program in my County, who told me the fact that I didn't sign a Certificate of Irrevocability and Waiver isn't relevant in my case, due to the fact that I signed a consent to entry of stipulated judgement terminating my parental rights.

Why does a stipulated judgement mean the requirements in ORS 109.321 do not need to be met, for any consent I signed to be irrevocable?

Answer (score 1):

That law specifies 6 exceptions (ORS 109.323-109.329). A stipulated judgment, which is an agreement to settle a case, itself doesn't mean that, but the circumstances of the agreement, could (if it terminates parental rights).